# Como concatenar dos campos?

Tags: php, mysqli

Veran este código es de un autocomplete que funciona con PHP y JQuery y un poco de Ajax. Funciona, porque escribo nombres y me salen los nombres de la base de datos.Pero lo que también necesito es que me ayuden a concatenar el nombre y el apellido.Para que me salgan en la misma consulta. Uno al lado del otro.

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['query']))
{

$output = '';
$query = "SELECT nombre FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE '%". $_POST['query']."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

          $output .= '<li><a href="www.google.com.do">'.$row['nombre'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
else
{
     $output .= '<li>Not found</li>';
}

$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;
```

}

?>

Comment: de la misma forma como muestras el nombre puedes mostrar el apellido `<a>'.$row['nombre'].' '.$row['apellido'].'</a>` Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo por php o por mysql con la función CONCAT:

**PHP**

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {

    $query = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE '%". $_POST['query']."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $output .= '<li><a href="www.google.com.do">'.$row['nombre'].' '.$row['apellido'].</a></li>';
        }
    } else {
        $output .= '<li>Not found</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
    echo $output;
}
```

**MySQL**

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {

    $query = "SELECT CONCAT(nombre, ' ', apellido) as nombre_completo FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE '%". $_POST['query']."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $output .= '<li><a href="www.google.com.do">'.$row['nombre_completo'].</a></li>';
        }
    } else {
        $output .= '<li>Not found</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: como pongo un espacio entre ambos?

Comment: El método que puse de MySQL lo hace, sin embargo ya hice la edición para hacer lo mismo en PHP.